# Ошибка запроса

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Всем привет!

```
    $connection = @mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die("Нет соединения с БД");
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8") or die("Не установлена кодировка соединения");

// получение массива информеров
        $informers = informer();

/* ===Информеры - получение массива=== */
function informer(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM links
                INNER JOIN informers ON
                    links.parent_informer = informers.informer_id
                        ORDER BY informer_position, links_position";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_query());

    $informers = array();
    $name = ''; // флаг имени информера
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        if($row['informer_name'] != $name){ // если такого информера в массиве еще нет
            $informers[$row['informer_id']][] = $row['informer_name']; // добавляем информер в массив
            $name = $row['informer_name'];
        }
        $informers[$row['parent_informer']]['sub'][$row['link_id']] = $row['link_name']; // заносим страницы в информер
    }
    return $informers;
}
/* ===Информеры - получение массива=== */
```

Выходит 2 ошибки: **Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in N:\home\programirovanie.ru\www\model\model.php on line 63**

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given in N:\home\programirovanie.ru\www\model\model.php on line 63**

63 строка это: **$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_query());**

Что здесь не так? 2 день уже думаю.

Comment: $connection не существует внутри метода. 

    die(mysqli_query())

повышаем внимательность к написанному.

Comment: @Etki, Сделал: $res = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_query());
Ошибки:Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in N:\home\programirovanie.ru\www\model\model.php on line 63

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given in N:\home\programirovanie.ru\www\model\model.php on line 63

Опять та же строка.

Comment: @DimasikYES, может, надо было не удалять $connection, а инициализирвоать его внутри метода?

Comment: @Etki, покажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: @DimasikYES

    function informer($connection)
    {
    //...

и передавать ему при вызове.

Comment: @Etki, Спасибо большое!) Все получилось! Сделайте ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function informer($connection)
{
```

//...
и передавать ему при вызове (`$connection`).

```
// получение массива информеров
$informers = informer($connection);
```